# Associated Model Attribute Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Rails novice here. I have associated models `Team` and `Venue` defined as follows:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :home_venues, class_name: "Venue"
end
```

and

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true, foreign_key: :team_id
end
```

Both models have attributes `:city` and `:region`. When I call `team.home_venues.create`, I would like for the `:city` and `:region` values of newly-created `venue` to default to the `:city` and `:region` values of the creating `team` unless otherwise specified.

What's the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use before_validation hook - this way you will make sure you will have all validations run at correct time. In your `Venue` model:

```
before_validation :set_default_values

def set_default_values
  self.city ||= self.team.try(:city)
  self.region ||= self.team.try(:region)
end
```